# In Vaadin what are the advantages of using a Panel over a VerticalContainer?

Tags: vaadin

In Vaadin what are the advantages of using a Panel over a VerticalContainer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Panel contains a VerticalLayout by default, but you can change that to any other layout you wish.

So you can't really speak of advantages per se, just additional features on top of the VerticalLayout.

The Panel component provides scrolling and possible visual decorations around the content it encapsulates. That's pretty much it.